# Can't write JSON to peripheral with CoreBluetooth

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I have a paired bluetooth peripheral which I have to send some credentials in a JSON like as follows

```
{"SSID":"WIFI_SSID", "Password": "WIFI_PASSWORD"}
```

And after the information has been sent the peripheral should connect to the provided WiFi credentials but I'm not completely sure the process is being performed correctly.

As soon the bluetooth peripheral has connected I start the process,

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

    // As soon as the device has connected 
    peripheral.delegate = self
    // Only discover the service I know it's for writing
    peripheral.discoverServices([SERVICE_UUID])
}
```

The `discoverServices` will call the `peripheral(:didDiscoverServices error)`

```
func peripheral( _ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    for service in peripheral.services! {
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
    }
}
```

Calling the following method where I do all the logic

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        let characteristic = characteristic as CBCharacteristic

        debugPrint(characteristic.properties)
        // This prints the following properties, reading + writing
        // __C.CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue: 10)

        if characteristic.uuid.isEqual(RX_UUID) {
            do {
                let msgDictionary = ["SSID": wiFiCredentials.SSID, "Password": wiFiCredentials.Password]
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: msgDictionary,options:[])

                peripheral.writeValue(jsonData, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                debugPrint("Error in auth message JSON: \(error.description)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Up to this point I think everything it's correct. After calling `writeValue` and setting the `type` to `CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse` I should expect something in the `peripheral(:didWriteValueFor characteristic: error)` method. What I receive in that method is the next error

```
Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 \"Writing is not permitted.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.}"
```

What I guess is that when I write the JSON value I shouldn't use the `.withResponse` flag and use `.withoutResponse`. If I do so I get the following log in the console.

```
[CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Characteristic <CBCharacteristic: 0x28388a040, UUID = 3E9D2532-2F00-11E9-9602-A44CC81C989A, properties = 0xA, value = (null), notifying = NO> does not specify the "Write Without Response" property - ignoring response-less write
```

Which confirms to me that I have to use the `.writeWithResponse`.

Is there something I am missing in the process? The JSON has to be sent using GATT and AFAIK this is the correct approach to do it. Are the printed `CBCharacteristicProperties` correct?

Things I've done:

- The JSON is not the problem. I've tried writing a random variable `"1".data(using: .ascii)` and still receive the same error.

Comment: Try using an app like lightblue and see if you also get an error there.

Comment: I've done that, I don't receive an error there.

Comment: the code looks correct, long shot, but you can also add a delay before writing the value. I have seen peripherals that take a few seconds to initialise before accepting values.

Comment: also make sure you need to write to the characteristic and not the descriptor